# Executing multiple stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to execute multiple stored procedures in a single transaction window. I am trying to do something like this :

```
 CREATE PROC #MainProc2
 AS
     DECLARE @key nvarchar(50) =  N'14'
     DECLARE @ret INT

     EXEC @ret = [DB1].P1 @KeyList = @key

     IF @ret <> 0
        RETURN
     ELSE
        PRINT 'P1 executed successfully'
        EXEC @ret = [DB1].P2 @KeyList = @key

        IF @ret <> 0
            RETURN
        ELSE
            PRINT 'P2 executed successfully'
```

This does not return any value. On executing, just gives Command(s) completed successfully. When I query the tables the stored procedure is supposed to populate, it's not updated so basically the store procedures never ran. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data, specifically @ret.

Comment: Yup, likely it is returning when @ret <> 0.  Your call to P1 is probably failing.